# Create a list of a scripts tikinter widgets

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a list of all tkinter widgets present in a script. I will use this list in order to call some properties of an element.

I know that I can call all the widgets using an iterator, like this:

```
window.update()
for child in window.children.values():
    print(child.winfo_width())
```

However I am trying to find a way to do this:

```
## Code is not working, is just an example
listt=window.children.values()
print(listt[0].winfo_width())
```

So, how can I create a list of the script's tkinter widgets, so that I can call an element and use it to find the widget properties?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to make a widget list in tkinter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert it to a list firstly,because `window.children.values()` will return a `'dict_values'`,so you couldn't use index directly.

Your code maybe like this:

```
listt = list(window.children.values())
```

Then you could use index to search it.

```
print(listt[0].winfo_width())
```